# Access to a protected network share using Win32 C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there a way to access a login/pass protected network share, to list files and get their names and creation dates, using the Win32 C++ API ?
I do not want the samba network share to be present in my explorer. (this can be done with WNetAddConnection2 method).
Thanks for all.

Comment: Network connections are maintained per-session.  Run your program in a different login session via `CreateProcessAsUser` from the processes you want unable to use the connection.  (Note that this is completely different from assignment of drive letters which are also per-session, and also I believe it's separate from user accounts.)

Comment: I have to wonder about a design that requires storing credentials in an application without letting the user access them.  Once the application is on the computer, it should be assumed to be under the complete control of any account with permission to access the application files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I agree with the objections Ben raises in his comment, you can keep using the [`WNetAddConnection2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). When you pass in a `NULL` value for the `lpLocalName` parameter it will not map a drive, but will simply perform the authorization, and thus allow you to use the full `UNC` path to perform tasks such as enumerating the files on the remote system.

> **lpLocalName**: A pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the name of a local device to redirect, such as "F:" or "LPT1". The string is treated in a case-insensitive manner.
>   If the string is empty or if lpLocalName is NULL, the function makes a connection to the network resource without redirecting a local device.

The MSDN page pretty much gives the skinny on using it, but something akin to (I don't have a windows box at hand to verify any of this code works):

```
NETRESOURCE resource;
resource.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
resource.lpLocalName = 0;
resource.lpRemoteName = L"\\\\server\\share";
resource.lpProvider = 0;
DWORD conResult;
DWORD result = WNetAddConnection2(&resource, L"password", L"username", CONNECT_TEMPORARY);
if (result == NO_ERROR) {
    // Go hog wild with files in \\server\share
}
```

To finish using it do:

```
DWORD retval = WNetCancelConnection2(L"\\\\server\\share", 0, TRUE);
```

Now bear in mind, if you've already established a connection to the server using different credentials, then I'm pretty certain the connection will fail

Comment: Beware that the connected share will still show up in the output of `net use` and will be accessible to any other processes running as the same user in the same session while it is connected.

Comment: @AndrewMedico never said it wasn't the case. If you use the windows API then you play by the API rules which state that the connection is for the session. I'm not aware of any C/C++ libraries that provide access to a samba share without some porting work for Windows.

Comment: I sometimes get a ERROR_NO_NETWORK when trying WNetAddConnection2. The network is accessible ...

Comment: There are several reasons for getting `ERROR_NO_NETWORK`, most of them name lookup related (the servername can't be resolved for some, unknown reason). You might have better luck by performing a retry, changing to using an IP address for the server.

Comment: This error was because my service was starting before network was up. When I try the previous code in a typical Win32 user app, it works fine. But, when I use it in a service, it does not work (error 1312 ERROR_NO_SUCH_LOGON_SESSION). It seems it does not work in a service as I found browsing the web ... Username of the service is System

Comment: I think if the service is running as LocalSystem then it won't be able to connect to the network, which yields that error. You may be able to get it to work by using impersonation, or alternatively by running the service under an account that has access to the controlled resource.