# Access network share from service with another user

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service, network-shares

I have a service that lives in a quite restricted server system. It must run under a specific user, let's call it user A.

The service must also be able to access a network share which user A does not have access to, but user B has. So the service must access this network share as user B, while running as user A.

The way I would do this if running locally on the computer is to map a network drive under a different user. But services can't access mapped network drives, even if it was mapped under the same user:

[Services and Redirected Drives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685143.aspx)

Does anyone have a suggestion to what I could do? I'm the creator of the service so I can modify it as I please. Is there perhaps some way to let it access the network share as another user via a winapi call (unmanaged C++)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article you link to says:

> Instead, the service should use client impersonation to impersonate the user.

In this context, that means using [`LogonUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

One caveat: that will only work if you are in a domain, i.e., the account that you want to log into the network server with is also valid on the local machine.  If not, then you will have to establish a network connection explicitly using `WNetAddConnection2` or similar.  It is technically true that this risks exposing the connection to other services, but the risk is minimal in most contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I think this SO post might actually be the answer I'm looking for:
[Access to a protected network share using Win32 C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271418/access-to-a-protected-network-share-using-win32-c)

Unless anyone has a better idea or other objections?

Comment: Yes, that should work.  But you could in fact map a drive letter if you wanted to; it *does* work, provided you map the drive letter *in the same session that you want to use it in*, i.e., from the service itself.  Since you're running as a specific user, interference with other services shouldn't be a problem either.  Nonetheless, impersonation (as recommended by Microsoft in the article you link to) would probably be a better choice.

Comment: So would `WNetAddConnection2` as suggested by the other SO thread be a good choise for impersonation or is there a more appropriate function, like one of the ones listed at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376391.aspx ?

Comment: `WNetAddConnection2` isn't an impersonation function.  To follow Microsoft's advice, you would use `LogonUser` and `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` - of course, that assumes that you're in a domain, so that the user account you want to use for the network connection is also valid for the local machine.

Comment: Ok if you create an actual answer from this I'll mark it as the accepted answer as it seems to be the most correct way of handling the problem.